# Equivalent of VINO in Red Hat

Tags: rhel, vnc

Vino is a VNC server which is installed by default on Ubuntu (Debian family). Is there a VNC Server installed by default on Red Hat, is it the same?

Comment: yes `vino` only, if you don't find, install using `# yum install vino` OR use `tigervnc-server`

Comment: # yum install vino
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `vino` only, if you don't find, install it using:

```
# yum install vino
```

If you encounter a problem doing so with `yum`, then try to configure registering it:

```
# rhn-register
```

Of course if you have RHEL licensed, otherwise try creating [your own repository](http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/setup-local-yum-server-in-centos-6-x-rhel-6-x-scientific-linux-6-x/).

As an alternative, you can also find vino packages on your RHEL media, installing it using this simple `rpm` command:

```
# rpm -ivh vino-<version>.rpm
```

If you cannot find there, download it from [rpm.pbone site](http://rpm.pbone.net/).

Comment: i have got this message : Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do

Comment: see if the package is already installed : `# rpm -qa | grep vino`, if it is not then the problem is in your yum configuration

Comment: yep >> # rpm -qa | grep vino
vino-2.28.1-3.el6.x86_64

Comment: then it is already there in your machine: System-->preferences->Remote Desktop  OR command: `vino-preferences`

Comment: i use ssh protocol to connect to server. GUI is not allowed

Comment: Is this problem in VNC server/client ?